# Does Mono 2.10 supports Open Xml Sdk 2.0 or not?

Tags: monodevelop, mono-framework

I have my C# Windows based Application and using open xml sdk2.0 for accessing ms-office documents.Its working good with .NET.But Now i trying to run my Exe With Mono Compiler then it displays below mentioned error messages.Please anybody having solution abt whether Mono 2.10 supports Open Xml Sdk 2.0 or not?....

1.Momo Report:

[image]

2. Mono Error Message:

[image]

what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

OpenXml is specific to Office, so: No, you'll need to look for a port if you want OpenXml on Mono.